# Is it possible to iterate over all instances of a JavaScript pseudoclass?

Tags: javascript, iteration, global, pseudo-class

I'm looking for a way (preferably without constructing a container they are added to) to loop through all instances of a JavaScript pseudoclass without looping nesting the instances off and looping through all children recursively of the window object.  Is this possible or do I have no recourse but to create an array holding all instances of any pseudoclass I want to access all the instances of?

Comment: Can you clarify the situation? What "pseudo classes" are there? You mention the `window` object, do you mean HMTLElement instances in the DOM?

Comment: If by "pseudo class" you mean constructor functions, then yes, you have to manually keep references to all created instances.

Comment: pseudoclass meaning something like function A() { this.foo = 'bar'; } function A_B(newFoo) { this.foo = newFoo; } A.prototype.constructor = A; A.prototype.B = A_B; - I'm looking for a way to access object inheriting from a known prototype (in the example "A.prototype") without maintaining a list or looping through all known objects recursively and hoping it is accessible from the top level.

Comment: Ok. As I said, it's not possible, since the an object does not know what other objects inherit from it. It's a unidirectional relation (from object to prototype). And not all objects are reachable via recursing over window. You don't have access to local variables in functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to create a static instances property to extend objects for the application then.

Comment: Please tell us for what exactly you would need this; there are few use cases. With a static list you will need to do "Garbage Collection" manually, it easily leads to memory leaks if not done properly. Likely there is a better solution for your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this with the following code (and got rid of the need to create a dummy instance of objects for each inheritance in an inheritance chain):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'constructing', {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: false
});
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'construct', {
    enumerable: false,
    get: function () {
        if ((this === Object) || (this.constructor === Object)) { return; }
        if (this.constructing === false) {
            this.constructing = this.__proto__.constructor;
        }
        if (this.constructing.hasOwnProperty('instances')) { this.constructing.instances.push(this); }
        var c = this.constructing;
        if ('base' in c) {
            this.constructing = c.base;
            this.constructing.call(this);
        }
        if (c !== this.__proto__.constructor) {
            for (var i in c.prototype) {
                if (!this.__proto__.hasOwnProperty(i)) { this.__proto__[i] = c.prototype[i]; }
            }
        }
    }
});

function A() {
    this.construct;
    this.foo = 'foo';
}
function A_bar() { console.log(this.foo + 'foo'); }
A.prototype.constructor = A;
A.prototype.bar = A_bar;
A.instances = new Array();

function B() {
    this.construct;
    this.foo = 'bar';
    var base = this.__proto__.constructor.base.prototype;
}
function B_bar() { console.log('bar'); }
B.base = A;
B.prototype.constructor = B;
B.prototype.bar = B_bar;
B.instances = new Array();

document.write(A.instances.length);
document.write(B.instances.length);
var a = new A();
document.write(a.foo);
document.write(A.instances.length);
document.write(B.instances.length);
var b = new B();
document.write(b.foo);
document.write(A.instances.length);
document.write(B.instances.length);
var c = new B();
document.write(c.foo);
document.write(A.instances.length);
document.write(B.instances.length);
a.bar();
b.bar();
c.bar();
```

Output:

```
00foo10bar21bar32
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, since the an object does not know what other objects inherit from it. It's a unidirectional relation (from object/instance to prototype).

And not all objects are reachable via recursing over `window`. You don't have access to local variables in functions.

You have to keep track of created instances manually.

Comment: Is there a way to prepend commands to an object's constructor in a manner that will ensure they are executed even if the object is later inherited?  As an example I have this: Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'instances', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: new Array()
});

function A() {
    this.__proto__.instances.push(this);
}
A.prototype.constructor = A;

document.write(A.instances.length);
var a = new A();
document.write(A.instances.length);
var b = new A();
document.write(A.instances.length);

Comment: Which requires the line "this.__proto__.instances.push(this);" to be placed in the constructor for it to function - is this something that can be automated for all Object's (just for the sake of this example) rather than manually inserting it in each constructor derived from Object?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. But may I ask why you are doing this anyway?

Comment: I'm writing a JavaScript DB (designed for deployment on a modified version of Chrome that bypasses the 5MB local storage limit) that synchronizes with a PostgreSQL DB and other clients via socket.io communications to a node.js server where the data in the DB consists of objects (code loaded from the DB, rows can have stored properties [columns] and state properties [not stored, but created after the code footprint is loaded in], methods, events and subclasses - tables can act as classes and the DB-specific code goes straight to window).  It's for an internal BI application.

Comment: Code can change on the fly to some extent, so I'd like to be able to track instances of pseudoclasses as seemlessly as possible and update properties as quickly as possible, I added a "lazy" property to the schema defining properties (so if they are defineProperty generated with value and no get/set they delay actual definition until a get/set is called, when the actual property is placed on the object, but so they can still use "this." to access local memebers - but am trying to find a seemless way to implement the non-lazy definitions).

Comment: I see. Have you considered using a factory to create the instances? The factory method can then keep track of them.

Comment: The rows start as normal name/value paired objects inherited from a table-specific Template pseudoclass based on Object - properties, methods, and subclasses are wired directly to it's prototype.

Comment: I really need to be able to use the new/delete commands for my application (it relies on being able to manipulate tens of thousands of pseudoclasses, creating and destroying them as needed without reloading the browser) and to have access to the prototype object.

Comment: What's wrong with lazyness? Do your added properties have any "initialisation sideeffects"?

Comment: In most cases laziness works, but if a member that a property relies upon for it's initial value changes after the property has been created but before the property has been accessed there would be issues.